# How can i break a for in loop from nested forEach Function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, break

I have a this loops

```js
for (var key in params) {
  if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
    params[key].every(function(item) {
      let value = something(item.start, item.end);
      if (value === item.start || value == item.end) {
        return false // break
      }
    })
  }
}
```

When i set `return false` to stop the `every()` function i also want to stop the first loop. How can i do that? I tried this:

```js
OUTER_LOOP: for (var key in params) {
  if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
    params[key].every(function(item) {
      let value = something(item.start, item.end);
      if (value === item.start || value == item.end) {
        return false // break
        break OUTER_LOOP; // not working
      }
    })
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work in this way... so how can i stop the `every()` function and the first loop at same time correctly?

Comment: can you share the content of param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return `true` for exit `some` and use the returned value of `some` for breaking the loop.

```
for (var key in params) {
    if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
        const
            leave = params[key].some(item => {
                let value = something(item.start, item.end);

                // exit condition should return true/truthy value
                // for leaving the outer loop
                return value === item.start || value == item.end;
            });

        if (leave) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but `return true` doesn't stop the `for (var key in params)` loop

Comment: yes, please see edit. the result needs to bubbled outside with a check.

Comment: thank you, I have updated my code again, because I forgot something... does it still work with `some()`? could you take a look again?

Comment: thanks for you update. But i have one problem. `something()` returns for e.g. a float value like `0.99` if the `item.end` is `1` so the loops ends before `1` so in my console.log() i see it ends with `0.99` instead of 1. How can i change the if condition, so i can also see 1 once and then the loop breaks? or do i need to pass my other stuff before `return value` ?

Comment: you could round the value ...?

Comment: I've thought about it, but unfortunately I can't, because the values are used for an animation...

Comment: like this: `return value === item.start || parseInt(value) === item.end` ?

Comment: or `Math.round`.